# EntityFramework transaction over multiple contexts instantiations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, transactions, oracle11g

I trying to understand how I can make transactions work with my project. I use EntityFramework 4 with an Oracle 11g database.

Here his the deal, I have a lot of operation to do, and I want to roll back when an unexpected exception is thrown. I have multiple class with simples operation, each class create it's own Context and make some change, for example :

```
public class OneDaoFactory
{
    public int AddTreatment(Dto dto)
    {
        using (Context bdd = new Context())
        {
            //Make some changes in database
            bdd.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have business wich will call methods from the factories:

```
public void Business()
{
    try
    {
        OneDaoFactory.AddTreatment(dto);
        SecondDaoFactory.Add(dto2);
        throw new Exception("make a rollback");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //rollback
    }
}
```

Is there any way to create a transaction in the business that will manage all the contexts created by the factories ? Other than create a Context in the business and pass it over to all the DaoFactories ?

I found things about `TransactionScope`, but from what I saw, it is for SqlServer. I tried to manually open a connection and a transaction but the contexts seems to reopen theirs owns, so my rollback did nothing.

**EDIT**

If possible, I would like to not include reference to EF in the business. Like using another Factory to open and close the transaction

Comment: By default, if a connection is opened inside TransactionScope it will be enlisted into the ambient transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by opening your own connection `EntityConnection`, then open a transaction and pass the connection to the object contexts:

```
public class OneDaoFactory
{
    private EntityConnection conn; // initialize from outside

    //...

    public int AddTreatment(Dto dto)
    {
        using (Context bdd = new Context(conn))
        {
            //Make some changes in database
            bdd.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


public void Business()
{
    EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(ConnectionString);
    OneDaoFactory.SetConnection( conn );
    SecondDaoFactory.SetConnection( conn );

    using( var ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        OneDaoFactory.AddTreatment(dto);
        SecondDaoFactory.Add(dto2);
        throw new Exception("make a rollback);

        ts.Complete();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, I would have prefer to not include reference to Entity in my business, but it seems like I will have to.